# Scrapy throws "ModuleNotFoundError" upon execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a very basic spider in scrapy to scrape the title of questions from the landing page of stackoverflow. I've been trying to make it work for the last few hours but I get the same error every time I execute my script. The full traceback is given below.

`items.py` includes:

```
import scrapy

class StackoverflowspiderItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
```

`infograbber.py` aka spider contains:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from stackoverflowspider.items import StackoverflowspiderItem

class InfograbberSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'infograbber'
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/']

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        items = []
        for question in sel.css(".question-hyperlink"):
            title = StackoverflowspiderItem()
            title['name'] = question.css("::text").extract_first()
            items.append(title)
        return items

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

})
c.crawl(InfograbberSpider)
c.start()
```

This is the `Project Hierarchy`:

[image]

The error I'm having:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\stackoverflowspider\stackoverflowspider\spiders\infograbber.py", line 4, in <module>
    from stackoverflowspider.items import StackoverflowspiderItem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stackoverflowspider'
```

FYI: when I try like below then it works but I do not wish to go like this.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class InfograbberSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'infograbber'
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for question in response.css(".question-hyperlink"):
            print(question.css("::text").extract_first())


c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

})
c.crawl(InfograbberSpider)
c.start()
```

Where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance for any solution. Btw, I'm using `python 3.6` and `scrapy 1.5.0`. I've tried with `cmd` and `sublime text editor` to execute the file but in both cases I get the same error.

Comment: can you show how do you run your spider ?

Comment: Did you try `from stackoverflowspider.stackoverflowspider.items import StackoverflowspiderItem`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, sir but found the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your problem is that you execute the `spider` like so:

```
python infograbber.py
```

but you need to go in your folder where is `scrapy.cfg` and run scrapy like this:

```
scrapy crawl infograbber
```

Comment: Thanks @Druta Ruslan for your solution. It worked finally. I didn't know this information concerning `scrapy.cfg`. However, can you suggest me how can I run the same from sublime text editor using `.CrawlerProcess()` as I've shown above? Can I move `scrapy.cfg` into either of the folder within my project? Thanks.

Comment: sorry but i don't work with `sublime` i don't know what you can do there, you can search maybe is any questions about this here on stackoverflow

Comment: That doesn't have to be sublime. Any IDE like pycharm, anaconda, I meant other than cmd? Let us wait few more time if there is any related solution comes along. Your solution deserves a checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

This problem with scrapy not finding your needed package occurs if two conditions are fulfilled:

1. Your scrapy.cfg is not on the top level for your project
2. Your modules ".settings.py", ".middlewares.py", ... are not in a package declared directly on the project top level

What happens is that when you call scrapys "Crawlerprocess", it does not find your modules to import. It is locking for your ".settings" module. It does that by looking for your "scrapy.cfg" file. Since your "scrapy.cfg" file is in the wrong spot for scrapy to find it automatically, you need to help it:

1. In your case the folder for "stackoweflowspider.stackoverflowspider" should be in sys.path. (so do sys.path.append(), with the directory for that path). This would have been done by scrapys "get_project_settings()" function if it had found the "scrapy.cfg" file.
2. You also need to tell scrapy which module really is the ".settings" module. This you do by setting an environment variable called "SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE". Set it using

   ```
   os.environ.setdefault('SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE', "stackoweflowspider.stackoverflowspider.settings")
   ```

If you after that call CrawlerProcess with get_project_settings() as parameter

```
CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
```

then it will work. To set your USER AGENT info, you need to do one step more, but I here focused on the issue with scrapy not finding your package and modules.

Comment: As far as I remember, this is how I found it working `sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\stackoverflowspider')
`

Comment: Possible. At least that is enough to find the "scrapy.cfg" file. If that file defines the ".settings" module, then that is enough to make it work (then it sets the same environment module as mentioned above by reading from that file). I just prefer to move both tasks into python. Helps if you later want to use pyinstaller...

Answer (score 1):

Below code solved my problem:

```
from ..items import StackoverflowspiderItem
```