# ModuleNotFoundError while importing undetected_chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am importing undetected_chromedriver for a scrappy web scraping project. I keep getting this error however `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'undetected_chromedriver'`. Everything is installed and all the versions are up to date. Why would I be getting this error?

When I run `pip show undetected-chromedriver` I get

```
  Name: undetected-chromedriver
Version: 3.5.4
Summary: ('Selenium.webdriver.Chrome replacement with compatiblity for Brave, and other Chromium based browsers.', 'Not triggered by CloudFlare/Imperva/hCaptcha and such.', 'NOTE: results may vary due to many factors. No guarantees are given, except for ongoing efforts in understanding detection algorithms.')
Home-page: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver
Author: UltrafunkAmsterdam
Author-email: info@blackhat-security.nl
License: GPL-3.0
Location: c:\users\sekoc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages
Requires: requests, selenium, websockets
Required-by:
```

when I run `import sys; print(sys.path)` I get

```
['C:/Users/sekoc/OneDrive/Documents', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Panda3D-1.10.9-x64', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\sekoc\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0', 'C:\\Users\\sekoc\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python39\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Comment: _Why would I be getting this error_ Because your computer has two separate installations of python.  One of them knows about the module, and the other doesn't.

Comment: Show us the exact command you used to install the module.

Comment: I used pip install undetected-chromedriver and how do I get the other version of python to know about the module? I'm not using a virtual environment.

Comment: Show us the output of this command `pip show undetected-chromedriver` and also of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: I made the changes above. If undetected_chromedriver is in the wrong directory how do I change it?

Comment: Yes, it does look like you have two separate installations of python.  One is in `c:\users\sekoc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0`, and the other is in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0`.

Comment: Do you know how python got installed twice on your computer, in two separate locations?

Comment: I think I installed Anocnda and then python again when I got a new SSD. Should I just delete one of the pythons? Dose it matter wich one I delete because I can just reinstall the package?

Comment: Assuming nothing else on your computer depends on it, yeah just pick one and uninstall it.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work the other version of Python is a file owned by the system and I can not edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the internet for what felt like forever the solution turned out to be pretty simple. The scrapy.cfg was in the wrong place in the file. I figured this out after reading one of the solutions on this stack discussion [Scrapy throws "ModuleNotFoundError" upon execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159487/scrapy-throws-modulenotfounderror-upon-execution).

[This is what my hiarchy lookwd like orignaly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v85r.jpg)

[This is what my hiarchy needed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAdUA.jpg)